# How to generate SHA256 hash from inline javascript?

Tags: sha256, content-security-policy

I have the inline javascript that just contains `jQuery.noConflict();` within the src tags. I tried plugging this string into a SHA256 generator and it gives me `1B631C545E0E9ACDA2FA9ADEF7CE9415A95FC6A325EA80268D1793BF913180AE` which doesnt even look like the valid format to add to a whitelist for my content-security-policy.

Luckily chrome shows the expected hash `sha256-ewwxYHPE+l68SkoQL0cNlN2qNMJgDV+Bu7SNHV7o76k=` so i am able to add this to my whitelist instead. However, I am still curious what I am doing wrong

Comment: The hash must be base64-encoded. You can use https://report-uri.com/home/hash to generate a base64-encoded hash — or generate it from the command line using openssl, like this: `echo -n "jQuery.noConflict();" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl base64 -`. Note that both of those methods produce `hEo2wsQ3BMWuhG0PUgk0Y7xuhNVH0EUo7vtjExKeVw8=` as the base64-encoded sha264 hash for the input `jQuery.noConflict();`. So if the browser is showing something else as the expected value, I think your source must have some additional whitespace or newlines other than just  `jQuery.noConflict();`…

Answer (score -2):

Try an online hash generator like this one:

<s>https://approsto.com/sha-generator</s> (doesn't work anymore)

https://csplite.com/csp/sha/

As @sideshowbarker mentioned in their comment, sha256 value is base64 encoded, so that it becomes a clear text, safe to be used in http headers.

Comment: The link does not work for me